# Navigation Menu Causing Entire Nav Layer to Dissappear Html / CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm, attempting to create a drop down menu on my website and for the most part have been successful, however I'm having one issue.

```
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>
                content
                <ul>
                    <li>subcontent</li>
                    <li>subcontent</li>
                    <li>subcontent</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Above is the content

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

ul, li{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ff0000;
}

#nav ul{
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav ul li{
    min-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

#nav ul li ul li{
    display: none;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

And that is the CSS

Basically, because I'm positioning my content as 'absolute' in order to stop anything from being misplaced when the dropout menu is used, the layer black layer which acts as the navigation bar section ends up disappearing. Is there any way around this, or do I need to restructure my website completely?

This is what is looks like in a browser:

[image: Nav Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `background-color` to `ul, li`

```
ul, li{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

or give `#nav` a height

```
#nav{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ff0000;
 height: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for answering, I just figured this out, but thanks a lot any how.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized it was because I hadn't set a height in #nav.